# Is there a way to import/export Visual Studio .NET 2003 settings?

Tags: import, export, settings, visual-studio-2003

Is there a way to import/export Visual Studio .NET 2003 settings? Especially the IDE level include, reference, library and source files' settings accessible from the *Tools/Options/Projects/VC++ Directories* menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not.  Import / Export settings is a Visual Studio feature which was added to the 2005 version.  It exists in every version going forward but not backwards to 2003 or 2002.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it covers also your settings, but you can read [How To Import/Export VS .NET 2002/2003 Settings](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/13?n=how-to-importexport-vs-net-20022003-settings).